# SQL Images -> byte arrays

Tags: sql, image, etl

So I am importing some images stored in SQL image columns, and I need to change them to Byte arrays since I store my images as varbinary(max) and recreate them. I would LOVE it if there was a program to do this, or a really easy way since I don't have a ton of time.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image data type in Sql Server is a varbinary field that is being discontinued in future versions.

I would bet that a tool like [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) handles the "conversion" automatically. I use quotes because its a type conversion and not a format conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into writing a quick script in PowerShell? It has access to the full .NET framework, so should be somewhat simple if you're using those technologies.

Of course it's not simple if you have to learn PowerShell in order to write the script, but learning's always good :)